# reg match to search a string informatica with delimiter '/'

Tags: regex, unicode, regex-group, informatica, information-extraction

I have a string column with the below  sample data.

1) ABC/DEF/003 - This is for testing

2) XYZV/T&X/ABC/004 - This is for testing

3) ZXC/004/007 - This is for testing

4) This is testing

Using regextract/regmatch i need to search/extract  get only the below data

1) ABC/DEF/003

2) XYZV/T&X/ABC/004

3) ZXC/004/007

4) it should return null

I had used the pattern search as this  `(.*)([^A-Z0-9\/\._])` but it will not 
satisfy the last condition (4) data.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `(.*)([^A-Z0-9\/\._])` will first match all chars except a newline due to `.*` and captures that in group 1.

The second part uses a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matches 1 time any character that is not in the character class and captures it in group 2.

If you don't want to match the last condition you could make the regex more specific.

You could repeat the character class `[A-Z0-9._&]+`  and then repeat a group `(?:/...)`+ one or more times where the forward slash is prepended. There is an ampersand missing, you could add that as well.

Then match a space, `-` and a space. After that you could match any char except a newline 0+ times using `.*`

```
[A-Z0-9._&]+(?:/[A-Z0-9._&]+)+ - .*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/glVEQJ/1)